# Passing a variable from anchor tag inside <script> to a paragraph tag

Tags: javascript, html

How can I pass variable from anchor tag inside script tag to paragraph outside script?`

```
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
       <p id="test1"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    </div>
  </div>
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
<script>
   var VARIABLE = "abc"
   var container = document.getElementById("wrapper");
   var url = ['url_1','url_2']
   for( i=0; i<url.length; i++){
   container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<a href="#test1" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal"><img src></a>');
 }
</script>`
```

Comment: Why have you got an anchor tag within a script block?

Comment: Could you explain more about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: so this anchor tag is inside a for loop:
container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<a data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" ><img src="'+urls_1[i]+'" alt = "HTML5 Icon" border="5" style="width:228px;height:228spx;"></a>');

Comment: @sonal, i am not sure what your trying, if in case you are trying to assign the variable to anchor tag, use data attributes(ex:data-variable="+variable+") to anchor tag and with that data attribute assign it to paragraph....Hope it may give some idea...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion created :((((
I want the value of Variable declared inside <script> tag to appear in modai content.. and since calling modal is done in <a> tag is there a way to pass the variable from <a> to<p> inside modal-body?

Answer (score 0):

You must assign the anchor tag to a variable.

```
var anchor = '<a href="#test1" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal"><img src></a>';
```

And then set the value of this to the paragraph's inner HTML

```
document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = anchor;
```

You can combine these two

```
document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = '<a href="#test1" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal"><img src></a>'
```

There is also no need to have the `VARIABLE` text in the paragraph. Though, with all this being said; there's no need for you to do this with javascript at all. You could just have the anchor tag inside the paragraph tag as so

```
<p>
    <a...></a>
</p>
```

If this *isn't* what you were trying to achieve, could you please elaborate your question as it's kinda confusing.

Comment: OP said variable from anchor tag, not the whole anchor tag

Comment: I noticed, though I thought he meant replace `VARIABLE` with his anchor tag.

Comment: for( i=0; i<urls_1.length; i++){
 container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<a data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" ><img src="'+urls_1[i]+'" alt = "HTML5 Icon" border="5" style="width:228px;height:228spx;"></a>');
 //container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<p>'+c1[i]+'</p>');
 }
I want to pass a variable to pass to modal whenever I click on Image..

Comment: I think you did too.